# The Cloudera Manager Agent is not able to communicate with this Solr Server over the HTTP API. SSL&Kerberos

Tags: ssl, solr, kerberos, cloudera

I am using CDH5.4.7 i enabled kerberos and level1&2 TLS/SSL.. Successfully enabled for other CDH services except Solr... After enabling ssl for solr the following errors occurs.

**Solr Server API Liveness** Suppress...
The Cloudera Manager Agent is not able to communicate with this Solr Server over the HTTP API.

**Web Server Status Suppress..**.
The Cloudera Manager Agent is not able to communicate with this role's web server.

**In the solr server logs:**

**ERROR**   org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager
  ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

**ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn**
could not read the data
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /overseer_elect/leader

Error while calling watcher 
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@27cd611e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1ca30cfc[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]